# != operator returning true on false password values?

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I want to check if password input value is not equal to password 2 input value. Regardless of whether the passwords match it returns true.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form class='login' name='form'>
        <input id='pw' name='password' placeholder='Password' type='password'>
        <input id='pw2' name='password2' placeholder='Password Again' type='password'>
        <input class='animated' type='submit' value='Register'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.animated {
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.notEqual {
  background-color: red;
}
```

jquery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.animated').on('click', function (e) {
      if ($('#pw'.value) != $('#pw2'.value)) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('notEqual');
      } else {
          console.log("Passwords are equal");
      }
  });

});
```

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/vujitutere/2/

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you mean `$('#pw').val()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off:

```
($('#pw'.value) != $('#pw2'.value))
```

should be

```
($('#pw').val() != $('#pw2').val())
```

The way you've got it, you're looking at the `value` property on the string `"#pw"` and the `value` property of the string `"#pw2"`, which are undefined, passing undefined to jQuery, which gives you empty arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use jquery's `.val()`. Also, wrong syntax, method calls go outside the selector:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pvh7w2uh/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.animated').on('click', function (e) {
      if ($('#pw').val() != $('#pw2').val()) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('notEqual');
      } else {
          console.log("Passwords are equal");
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few mistakes in your jQuery:

```
  $('.animated').on('click', function (e) {
      //should be $('#pw').val() instead of $('#pw'.value)
      if ($('#pw').val() != $('#pw2').val()) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).addClass('notEqual');
      } else {
          console.log("Passwords are equal");
      }
  });
```